# PageReference - redirects in the Community Portal

Tags: apex, visualforce, customer-portal

Is it possible to use relative urls to access custom object pages and visual force pages with PageReference in the Community Portal?

I am looking for something like this:

```
PageReference congratsPage = new PageReference('/PartnerCommunity/s/myobject/MyObject__c');
```

Can you pls provide an example?

Cheers!

Comment: Have you tested or tried doing anything with regards to this? If so, what issues did you run into?

Comment: Hi Kris, thanks for the reply. I simply get 'invalid page' error or an outright Visual Force page error. I am curious to know what is the correct way of doing this to avoid issues when publishing changes to the production server from the sandbox.